# How to disable truezip recursive unzipping?

Tags: truezip

Is their any setting to disable truezip recursive unzipping? I want to copy inner Zip to a different path but unable to get inner zip as TFile instance.

zip:zip:file:/C:/Users/dbelwal/Documents/Autloader/tmp/6907267-xml.zip!/6907267-mm.zip!/ (expected FILE entry, but is a [DIRECTORY] entry)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is covered by the documentation of the TFile class:
https://truezip.java.net/apidocs/de/schlichtherle/truezip/file/TFile.html#verbatimCopy